# Is this machine good for post-run stretching?

Tags: stretching, machine

In Korea, there are many outdoor exercise machines in public places. This kind of machine is a particularly common one. 
Is this effectove as a post-run hamstring stretch? It feels good, but it is quite a fast, short-lived motion, unlike most other stretches such as a toe touch. 
Considering this is post run, maybe my muscles can take it as they've been warmed up.[image: Korean exercise machine]

Answer (score 2):

The machine you show is actually another type of [elliptical trainer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_trainer) typically meant for light exercise or cardio work.  I would suggest you look at performing some active stretching following a specific program for the hamstrings.  For example, following a [program](http://www.stretching-exercises-guide.com/hamstring-stretches.html) designed for the target muscle.  You may also want to search the [ExRx](http://www.exrx.net/index.html) site for stretches.

Comment: It isn't an elliptical trainer. At least, not in the traditional sense. Instead of simulating running, walking or climbing, it is used to recreate a swinging motion. Where you basically kick one leg in front of you, while the other is kicked behind. It stretches your calf muscles in a very similar way to a toe touch would do - unlike any elliptical machine I have ever been on (but maybe my definition of 'elliptical machine' is too narrow).